# Smaller down the image source inside imageview

Tags: android, image, imageview

So I have an image source inside the `ImageView`. I tried to smaller down the size of source by writing  `android:padding="25dp"`.

[image]

But when I captured the image and display the imageView, it become like this. The captured image does not fit into `ImageView`.

[image]

1. Is there a way I can smaller down the source in `ImageView` but allow the captured image fit into the `ImageView` ? Here my code:

   ```
   <ImageView
           android:layout_height="150dp"
           android:layout_width="150dp"
           android:background="@color/light_gray"
           android:padding="25dp"
           android:src="@drawable/camera"
           android:scaleType="fitXY"
           android:adjustViewBounds="true"
           android:id="@+id/imageView" />
   ```
2. Is there a way to remove the captured image but not remove the source? I used code below but it remove everything including the source.

   `imageView.setImageDrawable(null);`

Edit

Trying to place button in the center of imageView

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="42dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="42dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/camera"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonOne"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why my android layout cannot be displayed ?

Comment: Does your ImageView have a specific size? Can post your xml for the said ImageView as well?

Comment: because u have added the padding to 25dp, which is present even for the captured image.

Comment: @MuchOverflow I did post my xml, but it not displaying

Comment: @W4R10CK Is there any approach to solve ?

Comment: @JohnJoe, yes, I'm doing it right now

Comment: @W4R10CK Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @JohnJoe, see the code man and try. Im here for help

Comment: @W4R10CK ok,trying.

Comment: It would be better to use a placeholder image having some padding instead of set padding into `ImageView` and use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` attribute so that capture image will fit into the specified dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Button` to invoke the gallery or camera:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginRight="42dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonOne"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/your_delete_button_id"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginStart="35dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Use code for that:

```
    // buttons to access camera or gallery for input images
    Button imageButtonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonOne);
    imageButtonOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //invoke camera or gallery
        }
    });

    // image upload camera button are visible at first
    imageButtonOne.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

After image is selected and ready to be placed in `ImageView`, use this in your `onActivityResult()`:

```
imageButtonOne.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Delete button to delete image only:

```
    // image-delete button
    ImageButton buttonDelete1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.your_delete_button_id);
    buttonDelete1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (your_imageView != null) {
                // delete image from your_imageView
                your_imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
                // enable your camera_button again
                imageButtonOne.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else {
               //say something
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I saw error you should also write android_alignLeft... in element Button

Comment: How can I place the image button in the center of imageView ?

Comment: It seems like I need to have another `RelativeLayout`

Comment: use the imageview and button inside a relativelayout, and the delete button is for deletion, let me update that also in answer.

Comment: enjoy coding :)

Comment: `your_imageView.setImageBitmap(null);`

Comment: Yes, but I want to make the image null after delete. After run the  `your_imageView.setImageBitmap(null)` or  `your_imageView.setImageUri(null);`, this condition not getting executed. `if(imageUri==null) {
                        imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.tony.monthlyexpenses/drawable/calendar");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"No image",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132877/discussion-between-w4r10ck-and-john-joe).

Comment: Sir can we continue ?

Comment: Yes, come to the chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132877/discussion-between-w4r10ck-and-john-joe